# is there a way to have line amount higher than 6, when my array bound is set to 6?

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

I would like to print out more than six lines of six random numbers, but array bound is blocking me. I have set my array 'numbers' to six in order to always get just six random numbers, but now I dont know what to do to print out for example just ten lines of the numbers, because as I said - I can not due to six bounded array and I do not know how to deal with it. Can anyone help, please?

```
using System;


class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    Draw();
    Console.ReadKey();
}


static void Draw()
{
    int choice;
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    int[] numbers = new int[6];
    Console.Write("enter line amount: ");
    choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
        {
            numbers[i] = randomNum.Next(1, 49);
            Console.Write("{0} ", numbers[i]);
        }
       
    }
  
   
}
```

}

Comment: No with the primitive `int[]`, unless you're planning to write a code similar to Java's `ArrayList` to create a new array, double the side, and copy all the values. Instead, try to use a list such as `List<int> numbers = new List<int>();`, in this way you can add new numbers by applying `numbers.add(randomNum.Next(1, 49));`. Then, you can either print using the list, or you can convert the list into an Array (if that is what you want) with `numbers.toArray();`

Comment: Do you need the numbers later? Currently you don't need that Array at all. You could just throw the random number on the console without putting it into an array.

Comment: Yes, I am  required to use an array. My task is to store those random numbers to the array.

Comment: Is this becoming some kind of Lottery thing(49 sounds like a typical lottery thing) ? So you shouldn't have numbers twice in the array?

Comment: no no, that is not the case

Comment: I think there is error in code. In second `for` block `i` variable used instead of `j`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Hy!

In the 2nd for loop, write "j" instead of "i", because the 2nd for loop monitors the length of the array

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Draw();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static void Draw()
    {
        int choice;
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int[] numbers = new int[6];
        Console.Write("enter line amount: ");
        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                numbers[j] = randomNum.Next(1, 49);
                Console.Write("{0} ", numbers[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C# are of a fixed size, so I'd recommend using a dynamically-sized collection, such as a `List<T>` instead in your case.

There's a good introduction on how to use these on Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/arrays-and-collections) if you aren't familiar.

Comment: unfortunately, i have to use array to store the random numbers inside

Comment: Then this is impossible to solve. You can't store more numbers in an array then  there are spots in the array. Presumably you missed a detail in your "homework"? I you go a short written assignment you might want to show that in the question.

Comment: now I am thinking - shouldn't i just remove 6 bondage and then it would be possible to make? EDIT: did not help